Issue with CollectionView RemainingItemsThresholdReached event
I am facing 2 issues with the CollectionView:

I have given RemainingItemsThreshold="0" for CollectionView, but the RemainingItemsThresholdReached event is firing before reaching the last item. It is calling around 6 items before the last item.
WhenRemainingItemsThresholdReached is fired, I load the next set of data and append it to the CollectionView. But at that time, the CollectionView is scroll to the first item. It is not stay on the last item where we load more data.

My CollectionView Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    BackgroundColor="White"
    x:Class="NeedHelp.Pages.FriendDetailsPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#eeeeee">
                
            </Grid>

            <ScrollView 
                x:Name="frienddetails_scrollview"
                IsVisible="False"
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                
                <StackLayout
                    Margin="15">
                    
                    <Frame 
                        BorderColor="#efefef"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        HasShadow="False"
                        Padding="5">
                        
                    </Frame>

                    <Frame
                        BorderColor="#efefef"
                        Padding="3"
                        x:Name="map_layout"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        
                    </Frame>

                    <Label
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        x:Name="History_label"
                        Text="History"
                        TextColor="#424242"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                    </Label>

                    <Frame
                        x:Name="Tab_layout"
                        BorderColor="#efefef"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        HasShadow="False"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Padding="5">

                    </Frame>

                    <ListView 
                        x:Name="historylistview"
                        SeparatorVisibility="None"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <StackLayout
                                            Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                            
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <ListView.Footer>
                            <Label/>
                        </ListView.Footer>
                    </ListView>

                    <CollectionView 
                        x:Name="MyTweetsList" 
                        Margin="0,5,0,5"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="0"
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreTweets"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout
                                    x:Name="Item"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Orientation="Vertical">

                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>400</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>600</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>400</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <Label
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        IsVisible="{Binding ComingSoonVisibility}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="No Messages Yet."
                        x:Name="no_announcement_label"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            
            <Grid 
                x:Name="tweetBox"
                IsVisible="False"
                Margin="0,0,0,10">

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

Update
I have created a demo with this issue.
In this demo I am loading 50 items initially and after that loading 10 items. After loading the last 10, the collectionview scrolls to top and showing the initial items.

I created a new sample but I didn't meet the two issues. In my test, the RemainingItemsThresholdReached event  fired two times when the last items displayed.

I want to see the xaml structure. As a bare minimum - the container of your collection view.

@MatthewPans I can, but it should be part of the question, because tomorrow this link may be inactive. And then someone when searches to solve his problem, he wont be able to check it out. Just add something like : My CollectionView is inside "...".

@MatthewPans do not take this the wrong way, you are doing the right thing when stripping the question from irrelevant data. But the outside container, if unrestricted vertically, may cause the inside (your collection view) to be fully loaded. This is why it is important part of the structure.

@H.A.H. I have updated the question with the entire UI structure, could you please check now.

@MatthewPans For your CollectionView, set vertical restriction by setting "HeightRequest=500" or something like that.

@H.A.H. I already tried that, but no change

@MatthewPans change its orientation to horizontal then.

@H.A.H. For collectionview's inner stack orientation?

@MatthewPans I will try to explain it again. If I have a container, lets say vertical scroll view. That container is "bottomless". I can add more and more stuff to it. And if the items that I have inside are not height restricted, they will grow indefinitely. The container is important. The collection view should be restricted. Or - you can change its orientation. This way it works with horizontal scroll, and if your outer container is horizontally restricted, it will be fine. If you make only a grid, with only your collection view, and the problem is gone... you need to redesign.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@H.A.H. I have created a demo for this issue and added it on question, could you please check that?

Your main problem:
This line
AllItems = new ObservableCollection<UserTweetsList>(Items);

Is causing your whole collection view to refresh.
The whole point of observable collection is to make changes to the list. Recreating the collection, besides other performance issues, is the thing causing your scroll to go to the start.
Your solution:
Use AllItems = new only once.
And then use AllItems.Add(..) when you are loading items.
For example
if (!loadMore)
{
   Items.Add(new UserTweetsList() { tweetData = "message 1", tweetUser = "Albert});
   ...
   Items.Add(new UserTweetsList() { tweetData = "message 50", tweetUser = "Albert"});
   AllItems = new ObservableCollection<UserTweetsList>(Items); << move here
}
else
{
    AllItems.Add(new UserTweetsList() { tweetData = "message 51", tweetUser = "Albert" }); << change those lines to AllItems.Add not Items.Add

